# How could I add geolocation to OSQA?

Tags: python, django, geolocation, ip-geolocation, osqa

I want to modify it so questions made in a given location can only be answered by people in or near that location.

How do I do that? is there a location plugin for django I could use?

Answer (score 0):

http://geodjango.org/

There is no simple plugin per say, geodjango is an add on mini framework.  If you want to scale using a geo aware database is critical.

As a start you can represent locations as raw longitudes and latitudes without geodjango and do bounds comparison, but it will not be very efficient.  If you are serious about making something highly location aware geodjango is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [pygeoip](http://code.google.com/p/pygeoip/) or [Google's geolocation API](http://code.google.com/intl/es-NI/apis/gears/api_geolocation.html) and get the request IP and get the country/city of the user. After that just store it on your database and do the rest.